# Voyager relationship display multi names

Tags: php, laravel

am using voyager for admin panel and i have one problem my users table have first_name and last_name and in voyager it's only displays first_name because in relationship display the users i choose first_name because i can choose only one option but i need first_name and last_name to i searched and i found that i can do it like this.

in User class

```
    public function getFullNameAttribute()
    {
        return "{$this->first_name} {$this->last_name}";
    }

    public $additional_attributes = ['full_name'];
```

but how can i tell voyager that there is an accessor we want to use?

Comment: _because in relationship display the users i choose `first_name`._ I don't know Voyager, but I guess choose `full_name` instead ?

Comment: yes but there is not that option